# Microsoft Flow fails when trigger event is Create a File on OneDrive for Business

Tags: power-automate

I am triggering a flow when a new file is added to a folder (/Flows/InvoicesToXero/) in OneDrive for business.

However, it sees to think that the folder is a file and this causes issues:

{
  "status": 400,
  "message": "The file id '/Flows/InvoicesToXero/' is not valid.",
  "source": "api.connectorp.svc.ms"
}

This is probably the simplest flow you could have:   [image]

Full error here:  [image]

This is the json for the trigger:  (I have tried with and without a trailing slash)

```
{
    "inputs": {
        "host": {
            "connection": {
                "name": "@parameters('$connections')['shared_onedriveforbusiness']['connectionId']"
            }
        },
        "method": "get",
        "path": "/datasets/default/triggers/batch/onnewfile",
        "queries": {
            "folderId": "/Flows/InvoicesToXero",
            "maxFileCount": 10
        },
        "authentication": "@parameters('$authentication')"
    },
    "recurrence": {
        "interval": 5,
        "frequency": "Minute"
    },
    "metadata": {
        "b!caGb33cRrkC_foNq9zd0FIdP_xtQDcZEmqyeYyKvO6dYQu456-3vQaC_VKHi8b5w.014XBLOOWVAVAWSVA2QNELELS5LQI3SOJN": "/Flows/InvoicesToXero",
        "flowSystemMetadata": {
            "swaggerOperationId": "OnNewFiles"
        }
    },
    "splitOn": "@triggerBody()"
}
```

How can I trigger a flow when a new file is added to OneDrive for Business in a subfolder?

Comment: This is still broken in 2021.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to create another connector also named "When a file is created (properties only)", please refer to this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/onedriveconnector/#when-a-file-is-created-(properties-only)) and the screenshot below:

[image]

According to the screenshot above, we can see there are two triggers named "When a file is created (properties only)" and the second include sub folders.

Hope it would be helpful to your problem~

Comment: Hi Hury, unfortunately not. I tried both of those triggers with the same result